Retrieve slotted elements and put them into an array
I'm having a problem with Lit components I'm really not able to find a solution for no matter how hard I tried.
Here's how my <f-news-tags /> Lit component is used in Storybook:
const props = {
  tags: [
    {
      id: '605331e873b0c322aff5cce7',
      url: 'https://www.example.com/uno',
      label: 'Uno',
    },
    {
      id: '605331e873b0c322aff5cce8',
      url: 'https://www.example.com/due',
      label: 'due',
    },
 ......
}

<f-news-tags>
      <ul slot="list">
      ${
          props.tags.map((tag) => html`
            <f-news-tag slot="items"
              id=${tag.id}
              url=${tag.url}
              label=${tag.label}
            ></f-news-tag>
          `)
        }
      </ul>
    </f-news-tags>

It basically cycles through the tags array of objects and returns an <f-news-tag> for each object with the object data passed to it.
Here's how I built <f-news-tags>:
@customElement('f-news-tags')
export default class NewsTags extends LitElement {
  static override styles: CSSResultGroup = [componentStyles, styles];
  static dependencies = {
    'f-container': Container
  };

  @property({ type: String }) date: string = '12.12.2022';
  @property({ type: Array, attribute: false }) tags = [];
  @property({ type: Boolean }) showMore = false;

  @queryAssignedElements({slot: 'items', flatten: true}) listItems!: Array<HTMLElement>;

  override firstUpdated() {
    console.log("This is the array of items", this.listItems);
  }

  override render() {
    return html`
      <div class="wrapper">
        <f-container size="m" topspace="m" bottomspace="m">
          ${this.date ? html`<div class="date">${this.date}</div>` : ''}
          <slot name="list">
            <slot name="items"></slot>
          </slot>
        </f-container>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

And here's how I built the single <f-news-tag>:
@customElement('f-news-tag')
export default class NewsTag extends LitElement {
  static override styles: CSSResultGroup = [componentStyles, styles];

  @property({ type: String }) label = "";
  //@property({ type: String }) id = "";
  @property({ type: String }) url = "";

  override render() {
    return html`
      <li class="item">
        <a class="link" href="${this.url}">${this.label}</a>
      </li>
         `;
  }
}


As you probably noticed, the  is assigned to the 'list' slot and all <f-news-tag> items inside the  are assigned to the 'items' slot.
In <f-news-tags>, I'm trying to use the @queryAssignedElements (I've also already tried @queryAssignedNodes) decorator to get an array of the elements inside the 'items' slot. What I'm trying to achieve with this is to be able to conditionally render a show more/show less button when the cycled items exceed a given number. Despite all my efforts, however, the resulting listItems array is always empty.

Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.
